# Simple color scheme for sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm looking for a light color scheme for sublime text 2 but with few colors, 2 for example ,  like eclipse and netbeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try out the Earthsong theme which is quite simple, available at [github](https://github.com/daylerees/colour-schemes) - there's a screenshot of what it looks like here.

[image: earthsong light]

Comment: i'm not sure - it may be specified in the config file

Comment: The font is  : Source Code Pro

Comment: It was abode the screenshots on github page

Comment: aha... didn't think to look there

Answer (score 7):

You can preview and edit around 200 color schemes in [tmtheme-editor](http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com) 
On the Gallery Sidebar of the editor you can filter light and dark color schemes

[image]

I hope you can find your favorite one.

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of tmtheme-editor

Comment: I created a liittle [dotjs](https://github.com/defunkt/dotjs) script to [add keyboard shortcuts to the app](https://gist.github.com/macgyver/6074511) (press up/left to go next, down/right to previous)

Comment: Thanks @jon-z it's amazing. adding keyboard shortcuts for navigation is definitely on my list. I need to implement the focused feature first so that I can distinguish up and down key presses on the scopes list and on the gallery. None the less, you dotjs script rocks. love to see your contributions on github: https://github.com/aziz/tmTheme-Editor